# Getting/setting attribute values from XML

Tags: xml, vbscript

I've had a good look through the various answers for and come close but not quite hit it yet.

I have an XML file I'd like to test and if a certain attribute doesn't have the right value, then set it.  I'm using VBS.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
    <setting key="WindowsAuthenticationLoginEnabled" value=""/>
    <setting key="ServiceLocation" value=""/>
    <setting key="TimesheetLocation" value=""/>
    <setting key="GISLocation" value=""/>
    <setting key="Background" value="Dark"/>
    <setting key="AccentColour" value="aquamarine"/>
    <setting key="UseOnScreenKeyboard" value="false"/>
    <setting key="GpsType" value="External"/>
    <setting key="GpsComPort" value="0"/>
    <setting key="DocumentServerLocation" value=""/>
    <setting key="DocumentLocalLocation" value=""/>
    <setting key="ClientUpdateLocation" value=""/>
    <setting key="GisDownloadLocation" value=""/>
    <setting key="GisUploadLocation" value=""/>
</settings>
```

I'd like to test and set the value for which the key = "ServiceLocation" and "AccentColour".

Comment: share your efforts thus far ( your code )

Answer (score 0):

Solved this - turns out you don't need brackets around the arguments for setAttribute!

'objXMLNodeList.Item(i).SetAttribute "value","The value I'm trying to change it to"